# Estimating and checking the maximum of sin(t)+cos(t)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

This is a problem from *Calculus* by Gilbert Strang. But please note that at this point, the author has not yet introduced the formal definition of a derivative nor the concept of limits.

> Draw a graph of $f(t) = sin(t) + cos(t)$. Estimate its greatest height
>   (maximum $f$) and the time it reaches that height. By computing $f^2$ check
>   your estimate.

Since $sin(0) = 0$, $cos(0) = 1$ and $sin(\frac \pi 2) = 1$ and $cos(\frac \pi 2) = 0$, the maximum of $f$ should be in the middle. Based on that assumption, our estimate is $sin(\frac \pi 4) + cos(\frac \pi 4) = \sqrt 2$ at $t = \frac \pi 4$.

Now, $f^2(t) = (sin(t) + cos(t))^2 = 1 + 2sin(t)cos(t)$ so $f^2(\frac \pi 4) = 1 + 2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt 2}2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt 2}2 = 2 = (\sqrt 2)^2$.

I do not think I have really checked my estimate. Maybe I do not fully understand the problem. Where am I missing?

Comment: You mean, $ab$ is maximum _given that_ $a^2+b^2$ _is a constant_ ...

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Something comes to my mind: finding the largest area of a rectangle that has a diagonal of length one. It looks like the rectangle has the largest area when it becomes a square. But how do you prove it?

Comment: @W. Zhu Yes, by writing for example $a^2b^2=a^2(1-a^2)$ one sees that the area is maximum when $a=b=1/\sqrt{2}>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the idendity $$2\sin(t)\cos(t)=sin(2t)$$ we can conclude that the maximum is at $\ t=\frac{\pi}{4}\ $ because of $\ \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1\ $

Comment: Good catch. (+1)